# Prestashop 1.6: Bxslider "pager" is set to true but not showing on the slider

Tags: slider, prestashop, bxslider, pager

I set the "pager" to true in homeslider.js but it's still not showing on the home page slider. Though when inspected with firebug, the "pager" is actually there but not visible on the home page!

```
$('#homeslider').bxSlider({
useCSS: false,
maxSlides: 1,
slideWidth: homeslider_width,
infiniteLoop: homeslider_loop,
hideControlOnEnd: true,
pager: true,
autoHover: true,
auto: homeslider_loop,
speed: parseInt(homeslider_speed),
pause: homeslider_pause,
controls: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `homeslider.css`
2. Search:

`#homepage-slider .bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
     #homepage-slider .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -30px;
     width: 100%; }`

3. Change: `bottom: 0px`
4. If you work with "default theme" you should see below the "pager".

Success !